# How to add code to multiple pages at once

Tags: php

I'm running a wordpress theme that gets updated regularly. I have made some extensive modifications to it. Whats the best way to add all custom code to it at once? 
My idea is to put all my code in just 1 file. Accordingly to the page, it would fetch the necessary code from that file.
Is there something I can do instead of add

```
    <?php require("") ?>
```

for every page that I had modified?

Comment: take a look at VqMOd, it might come handy. But that's expensive, you'd better use some file modification if you care central file modification

Comment: You might consider including your file(s) from a single source (like functions.php), rather than on all the pages.

Comment: maybe http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes is a better solution, it depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You may insert your code in one of the static elements like Header or Footer sections,require is perfectly normal, just please use require_once function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php
Hope it helps you.